# How to return an action result of async Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this code but the controller is expecting a return type of ActionResult.
Why is the controller is accepting a Task> like this `return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();`(the default code when a controller is generated)?

```
//controller
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
{
        return await _userService.GetAll();
}
//service method
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
{
    return await _db.Users.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: @mjwills the compiler said 'cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<User> to ActionResult<IEnumrable<User> >
I'm thinking how can I return anActionResult<IEnumrable<User> >.

Comment: @ract Just return` IEnumerable<user>` from the controller.

Comment: @John Yes. It works if I change the controller into Task<IEnumerable<User>>. But I also need to return a NotFoundResult that is why it has to be a return type of ActionResult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> MyController()
{
    var res = await _userService.GetAll();

    if (res == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(res);
}
```

As a side note, I recommend changing `IEnumerable<>` to `IList<>`. It's not strictly correct to return a enumerable here and you can also run into "multiple enumeration" issues.

Comment: Why it is not in the ActionResult [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)?

Comment: Yeah. I was looking in the wrong documenation. Thanks!

Comment: Was about to say that. Correct one is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Also, I recommend returning a `IList<>` or something to avoid multiple enumeration problems.